# Seminorm is continuous regarding $\|\cdot\|$,

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, normed-spaces

> Let $E$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vectorspace.
>   Is $\|\cdot\|$ an arbitrary norm on $E$, then is every seminorm $p: E\to [0,\infty)$ continuous regarding $\|\cdot\|$.

I want to show this statement, but I am not sure what I have to do. I know what I have to do, when I have a system of seminorms:

Let $P$ be a system of seminorms on the $\mathbb{K}$-vectorspace $E$. Is $q: E\to [0,\infty)$ an arbitrary seminorm on $E$ then is $q$ continuous regarding $P$, if $\exists c\geq 0$ and $p_1,\dotso, p_n\in P$ with $q(x)\leq c\max\{p_1(x),\dotso, p_n(x)\}$ for all $x\in E$.

But now I do not have systems of seminorms. Can I do it similar?

So I have to find $c\geq 0$ such that $q(x)\leq c\|x\|$?

I would apprechiate just a clearification on what is to show, so I can try it myself first.

As a hint it is given to use, that norms are equivalent.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to show $p(x) \le c \|x\|$ where $c = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} p(x)$. For this you can take a base $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ and say $x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$ thus $p(x) = \ldots$

Comment: So I have to show, that $p(x)\leq c\|x\|$ for some $c\geq 0$ to get, that $p$ is continuous regarding $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: In general continuity wrt $\|.\|$ means $\lim_{\|x\| \to 0} p(x+y) =p(y)$ (uniformly wrt the direction from which $x \to 0$) but here what you want to show is conitnuity + bounded variations wrt $\|.\|$, because it is a consequence of the (uniform) continuity on $\|x\| \le 1$ together with $p(rx) = |r| p(x)$, $p(x+y) \le p(x)+p(y)$

Comment: Following your first comment, I can proceed like this: $p(x)=p(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^n p(a_ie_i)$, when $\vert|a\vert|=\max\{\vert|a_1\vert|,\dotso, \vert|a_n\vert|\}$, I can stipulate further $\dotso\leq\vert|a\vert|\sum_{i=1}^n p(e_i)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_1\dots e_n$ be a basis of $E$ such that $\|e_i\|=1$ for all $i=1\dots n$.
Let $x\in E$ with $x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i$.
Then we get 
$$
p(x) = p(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i) \le \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| p(e_i)
\le \max_{i=1\dots n}p(e_i) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|.
$$
The coordinate mapping $x\mapsto a_i$ is continuous from $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ to $\mathbb K$. Hence, there is a constant $c>0$ such that $|a_i|\le c \|x\|$.

This proves $$p(x) \le (c n \max_{i=1\dots n}p(e_i) )\cdot \|x\|.$$
The term in brackets is independent of $x$. Hence we obtain
$$
p(x-y) \le (c n \max_{i=1\dots n}p(e_i) )\cdot \|x-y\|
$$
and the mapping $x\mapsto p(x)$ is  is continuous from $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ to $\mathbb R$.